# Blazor - Force New Browser Instance?

Tags: browser, blazor

Say you're debugging using whatever default Browser you've selected.  Is there a reliable way to instruct Blazor to always open a new/distinct instance of that browser; so that the app you're debugging is always the only Tab?  I'm finding this happens sometimes, but not others.  However, I can't seem to track the circumstances that cause one condition as opposed to the other.

I could be wrong, but one problem that seems to occur (when a browser happened to contain open pages before you clicked 'IISExpress') is that a debugging session won't really end if you just close the tab you're testing.  Instead, the app will only close if you close the browser completely.

I'm aware I could just make sure I debug using a browser that I know is not containing other tabs at the moment... or just accept that I always need to close a browser entirely... but I'm hoping those aren't the only options.

Comment: RBee, thank you for your advice.  So far it worked well with both Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge; which is very helpful.  Btw, not a complaint, but I could not get your suggestion to reliably work with Firefox; and I did try some of their various 'arguments'.  Another note: I found it interesting... and a little frustrating... that the VS "Browse With" feature allows you to Add or Delete a Browsing option, but doesn't allow you to Edit an existing option.  Not a big priority, but if I missed something in this regard, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify arguments for browser launch profiles.

#### An example for Visual Studio with Chrome browser.

Click on the dropdown on the right of the start debugging button. Then select *"Browse With..."*

[image]

In **Program:** you add the browser executable file. And in **Arguments:** you add the arguments that you want to launch with the browser, for example to launch a guest profile you add the `--guest` arugment and for incognito/private mode you add the `--incognito` argument.

Here's a [comprehensive list of arguments](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) that you can use for Chrome.

[image]